# How to display address instead of co-ordinates in google maps navigation?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, navigation

I am opening google maps when user clicks on navigation button. But I want google maps to show coordinates in destination field instead of address. How can I achieve this?

I am using this code:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(lat),\(long)&zoom=10&directionsmode=driving")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```